# How to correct font adjustment button alignment

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have updated my code  so that the buttons can be seen in the nav bar and only target p tags with the id of "content" feel free to update the name to anything else for a project if some one is looking for  simple font resizer code. It will also save to local storage to keep the same font size throughout the page reload.

Thanks to those who helped me solve my original problem.

```
  <head>


  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js">


  </script>

  <!-- On click the positive and minus will increase or decrease the size of text -->
  <div class="button-div">
    <input type="button" value="A+" onclick="resizeText(1)" id="plustext">
    <input type="button" value="A-" onclick="resizeText(-1)" id="minustext">
  </div>

  <div class="flex-container">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Page 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  </div>

</head>

<body>
  <style>
    .button-div {
      display: flex;
    }

    .flex-container {
      display: flex;
    }
  </style>
  <!-- This text will increase or decrease depending on the button click -->
  <div id="content" class='row'>
    <span class="second">This text will be made bigger</span>
  </div>




  <script type="text/javascript">

    let fontSize = localStorage.getItem("myFontSize") || "1em";

    //  Any elements with content as the id will be increased or decreased
    var fontchanger = document.getElementById("content");

    fontchanger.style.fontSize = fontSize;

    function resizeText(multiplier) {
      // if (fontchanger.style.fontSize == "") { fontchanger.style.fontSize = "1.0em"; }
      fontchanger.style.fontSize =
        parseFloat(fontchanger.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + "em";
      localStorage.setItem('myFontSize', fontchanger.style.fontSize);
    }



  </script>

  </head>

  </body
```

>

Answer (score 2):

You can add a container for the buttons and set it to flex and flex-start to align the buttons to the start the container element.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div style="display: flex; justify-content:flex-start;">
    <input type="button" value="A+" onclick="resizeText(1)" id="plustext">
    <input type="button" value="A-" onclick="resizeText(-1)" id="minustext">
  </div>
  <div id="textDiv">
    <span class="second">This text will be made bigger</span>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function resizeText(multiplier) {
      if (document.body.style.fontSize == "") {
        document.body.style.fontSize = "1.0em";
      }
      document.body.style.fontSize = parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + "em";
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I try to change your code, so that you can understand the changes:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div class="row button-div">
  <input type="button" value="A+" onclick="resizeText(1)" id="plustext">
  <input type="button" value="A-" onclick="resizeText(-1)" id="minustext">
  </div>
  <div id="textDiv" class='row'>
    <span class="second">This text will be made bigger</span>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function resizeText(multiplier) {
      if (document.body.style.fontSize == "") {
        document.body.style.fontSize = "1.0em";
      }
      document.body.style.fontSize = parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + "em";
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

```css
.button-div
{
  display:flex;
}
```

this will not let increase the space between 2 buttons

if not believes me, have a look on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dupinderdhiman/cg5mws0n/7/

Comment: if any answers works for you, then upvote and mark it best answer, so that next visitor can easily understand the context of answer and question :) cheers BTW

Comment: I have updated the question with a new problem if you could take a look please.

Comment: what exactly do you want now? nav-menu in one row, with font size buttons?

Comment: I fixed the problem by giving the text  Unique id, Thank you.